# Как подключить файл .js к другому файлу .js?

Tags: javascript

Как подключить файл .js к другому файлу .js? Я не использую язык JavaScript внутри html-страницы, использую его, как язык для написания мобильных приложений для инструмента DroidScript. И так как долгое время программировал в Python, привык разделять код на полезные модули, да и вообще удобнее работать с небольшими файлами, нежели с трехэтажными мегакодами. Есть выход?

Comment: не скажу за серверный js (хотя там вроде за это отвечает requirejs), но в браузерном js широко распространяется практика сборки, когда код из нескольких файлов объединяется в один.

Answer (score 9):

```
function include(url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

Вызов:

```
include("/js/script.js");
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, это работает только в контексте html страницы. Я же не пишу код в браузере.

Comment: круто, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Внезапно хороший вопрос. Там нет явной поддержки включений, потому что авторы подразумевают компоновку через HTML-тэг script.

Однако все это можно обойти так или иначе:

**1 вариант:** jQuery однострочник

```
$.getScript("another_script.js", function(){alert("Загружено.");
//используем скрипт здесь
});
```

**2 вариант**: На первый взгляд он немного сумашедший, но можно самому  [динамически создать тэг script](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) как посоветовал @Hermann Zheboldov

Правда все это бесполезно если у вас нет браузера который обрабатывает HTML.

Поэтому я вижу только два варианта. Использовать [**препроцессор m4**](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) или обычный **[C препроцессор](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp.pdf)** для компоновки, либо так или иначе вставить туда код обрабатывающий HTML и использовать варианты выше(этот вариант значительно сложнее).

P.S. Возможно там уже есть какое решение пробелмы с включениями, стоит это проверить, так как я не имею никакого отношения к DroidScript и ничего о нем не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Собирать сборщиком, например:

https://github.com/bem/borschik

Соответственно будет какой-то один файл с инклюдами, на который Вы будете натравлять сборщик и получать на выходе собранный файл.

Answer (score 0):

Сам прогаю на DroidScript, и даже пишу движок на нем. Для подключения скрипта используй метод app.LoadScript('имя скрипта.js", callback); Вместо callback можешь вставить имя функции, которая выполнится после загрузки скрипта, но можешь просто указать имя скрипта, не добавляя callback

Answer (score 0):

за 7 лет наверное JS слегка поменялся, а я несколько часов назад начал знакомиться с hello world. Но сегодня же можно использовать import/export?

```html
// modulFirst.mjs
const valueFirst = 1
const valueSecond = '2'
export {
  valueFirst,
  valueSecond
}
```

```html
// ModuleSecond.mjs 
import {
  valueFirst, 
  valueSecond as valueSecondRename 
} from './moduleFirst.mjs' 

console.log(valueSecondRename) // '2'
```